# Finding different strings in two files - C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to export all lines from second file that aren't in the first one. The order of the lines doesn't matters, I just want to find ones that aren't in the first file already and save them to difference.txt.

Example:

### firstfile.txt

> This is first line
>   This is second line
>   This is third line

### secondfile.txt

> This is first line
>   This is some line
>   This is third line

***Now compare them...***

### difference.txt

> This is some line

---

This is what I came up so far. I know I need to loop through all lines in the second file and compare each of that line with each line of the first file. It's not making any sense to me why it isn't working

```
void compfiles()
{
    std::string diff;
    std::cout << "-------- STARTING TO COMPARE FILES --------\n";
    ifstream file2;

    file2.open("C:\\\\firstfile.txt",ios::binary);
//---------- compare two files line by line ------------------
    std::string str;
    int j = 0;
    while(!file2.eof())
    {
        getline(file2, str);
        if(!CheckWord(str))
        {
            cout << "appending";
            diff.append(str);
            diff.append("\n");
        }
        j++;
    }
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("C:\\\\difference.txt");
    myfile << diff;
    myfile.close();
}

bool CheckWord(std::string search)
{
    ifstream file;
    int matches = 0;
    int c = 0;
    file.open("C:\\\\secondfile.txt",ios::binary);
    std::string stringf;
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        getline(file, stringf);
        if(strcmp(stringf.c_str(), search.c_str()))
        {
            matches += 1;
        }
        c++;
    }
    if(matches == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for reading this block of text.

Comment: The output I get in difference.txt is an empty file and cout << "appending"; is never called although the files are different in some lines.

Comment: I imagine there are more efficient ways of doing this than rereading one file for each line you read from the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code doesn't do what you think it does:

```
if (strcmp(stringf.c_str(), search.c_str()))
{
    matches += 1;
}
```

`strcmp()` returns 0 when the strings are equal, but your code will not increment
`matches` in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple but much more effective and idiomatic solution using std::set:

```
std::ifstream file1("firstfile.txt");
std::set<std::string> str_in_file1;
std::string s;
while (std::getline(file1, s)) { 
    str_in_file1.insert(s);
}
file1.close();
std::ifstream file2("secondfile.txt");
std::ofstream file_diff("diff.txt");
while (std::getline(file2, s)) { 
    if (str_in_file1.find(s) == str_in_file1.end()) {
        file_diff << s << std::endl;
    }
}
file2.close();
file_diff.close();
```

Also, you might want to use a tool called *[diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)*. It does exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it manually then it sounds like you don't need a c++ program but you can do this from the command line using grep.

```
grep -vxFf firstfile.txt secondfile.txt > difference.txt
```